# Constraint margin not working properly on constraintlayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, layoutmargins

I am adding my views to constraint layout programmatically.
The view has an image and title which should come at the bottom of the image with some margin. When I am applying margin to the textview, margin applies to image as well.

Below is my code

```
set.connect(showimage.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 0);
    set.connect(showtitle.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, showimage.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 100);
    set.connect(showtitle.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, showimage.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
```

And this is the output i am getting can someone help me out

[image]

Comment: Post your XML too.

Comment: @Enzokie there is no XML i am doing this via java code

Comment: Not enough info for me to conclude! For workaround try replacing your second constraint with this
`set.connect(showtitle.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 100);`.

Comment: mention what do you want and what's issue

Comment: You can try scaling the image with  image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 1500, 1500, true);  and then set the constraint via percentiles instead of pd...so basicly set the constraints via percentiles so 10% from the right etc. then scale the image to fit into the constraints also add left and right constrints